# Getting HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to run Spring Framework project using Apache Tomcat Server (10.0.13 version). I am getting the above **HTTP Status 500** error while running all the JSP pages.
Error Message:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

**Type** Exception Report

**Message** /views/about.jsp (line: [16], column: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVrD.png)) JSP file [/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp] not found

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /views/about.jsp (line: [16], column: [2]) JSP file [/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp] not found
rg.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:343)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:479)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1796)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:202)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

**Apache Tomcat/10.0.13**

The code written in **About.JSP** page:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" />

<div class="container-wrapper">
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <p>We are a humble team who are passionate about helping our customers to get the best experience on music instruments and stuff.
        We are determined to provide the best products and services.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
      
 <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

The code written **Web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

  <display-name>Online-shopping-Spring-MVC-java-config-mysql-hibernate-master</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Screenshot of the Project Explorer tab

[image]

Build Source Path tab

[image]

I have tried to clean and publish Apache Tomcat Server multiple times but that didn't work.
Could you please provide me the steps to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please don't use images of text.

Comment: I have modified the question now as per your suggestion. Please help me on this.

Comment: What's at line 16 of `about.jsp`?

Comment: At line 16 the following code is written: <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>

Comment: And does `/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have already mentioned footer.jsp file path in the screenshot of the Project Explorer.

Comment: Does spring support Jakarta EE? Otherwise use tomcat 9

Comment: Also, using tomcat 9 I am getting the same error.